# How to draw a line of plusses og triangles along a path in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to draw a line with plusses or crosses along an given path (arch) but can't seem to find anything pointing me in the right direction.

Any help would me much appreciated.

Best, 
Jon H

Edit:
Hmmm. I still cant find any good answer to my question. I have googled for "everything"...I have fooled around with DrawingBrush'es with various LineGeometries or GeometryDrawings but cant seem to get a hang on it. Am I on the right coures or is there a better way? Can this be done in Blend/Design and exported in some way?

Answer (score 1):

One of the first hits of my google search:
Render Text On A Path With WPF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd263097.aspx

Comment: Thanks, jeroenh.

I saw this one too...but was looking for something like a way to draw lines with a pen with custom shapes. What i did't say in my original post was that I also need to show other stuff like squares and triangles.

Comment: then you should update your question to reflect what you really want ;-)